# Hard time understanding code with $.event.special

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm a new at JQuery and so was reading some random JQuery plug-in to help with my understanding of it. I arrived at the following code, and had some hard time understanding it.

```
/*
* smartresize: debounced resize event for jQuery
*
* latest version and complete README available on Github:
* https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.smartresize.js
*
* Copyright 2011 @louis_remi
* Licensed under the MIT license.
*/


var $event = $.event, resizeTimeout;

$event.special.smartresize  = {
    setup: function() {
        $(this).bind( "resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler );
    },
    teardown: function() {
        $(this).unbind( "resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler );
    },
    handler: function( event, execAsap ) {
        // Save the context
        var context = this,
            args    = arguments;

        // set correct event type
        event.type = "smartresize";

        if ( resizeTimeout ) { clearTimeout( resizeTimeout ); }
        resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery.event.handle.apply( context, args );
        }, execAsap === "execAsap"? 0 : 50 );
    }
};

$.fn.smartresize            = function( fn ) {
    return fn ? this.bind( "smartresize", fn ) : this.trigger( "smartresize", ["execAsap"] );
};
```

I read up on $event.special and identified setup and teardown--handler function though seemed random to me. I had no idea what execAsap was supposed to represent. And arguments just came out of nowhere.

Help me plx.

Comment: "ASAP" is an abbreviation of "as soon as possible", so "execAsap" means "execute as soon as possible". If the event is triggered with data argument that includes the string "execAsap" the underlying event handler will be run with 0ms timeout, otherwise will be debounced with 50ms timeout.

Comment: `arguments` is a variable that every function has. it's just a list of all the arguments that were passed to that function. so with the handler function we have `( event, execAsap )` but what if someone calls `handler(1,2,3,4);`? event will equal 1, execAsap will equal 2, and arguments will contain 3 and 4.